# Sharepoint 2010 cannot connect to WCF web service. TCP error 10061

Tags: web-services, wcf, sharepoint-2010

C# and Visual Studio 2013, SharePoint 2010.

My Sharepoint site needs to consume an external WCF web service exposed by another company.

I have written a WinForms test harness, and it works fine, so there are no firewall issues, and the endpoint is correct.

Now I have moved the code into a DLL assembly and called it from a SharePoint 2010 web part.

The method call to the WCF service errors with TCP 10061, "target machine actively refused the connection".

The SharePoint project and the DLL both have Service References (same as the Winforms harness). I have copied the ServiceModel section from the Winforms app.config to the SharePoint web.config.

I can create the Service Client object, but when I call a method on it, I get the 10061 error. Winforms app still works fine. Any ideas?